# CSS3: Floating first div between second and third

Tags: layout, html, css, css-float

Should be a simple solution to this:

I have the divs in the following order:

```
<div id="middle"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
<div id="left"></div>
```

I HAVE to have them in this order. Using floats, how can I get the first div (`"middle"`) to fall in between the second divs.

Each div has a set height and a set width (in px).

I've tried doing `float:left;` on the middle:

> [[middle] right] [left]

and then `float:right;` on the top cluster:

> [left [[middle] right]]]

but it shows up as

> [middle][left][right]

Any help?

**EDIT:** this is the current source:

http://pastebin.com/sjiw9PLn

http://pastebin.com/NMsWk1nZ

Comment: "I HAVE to have them in this order," then it's not going to be 'easy.'

Comment: Can you add some more divs as wrappers?

Comment: @DavidThomas - I figured as much :P

Comment: @bažmegakapa - Yes, that's fine.

Comment: Added sources that are currently used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can write like this:

```
div{
display:inline-block;
}
#left{
 float:left;
}
#right{
 float:right;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/8amez/

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. The middle column is at the top. If I do `.left`. and `.right` for the second/third class, the top div just stays on its own line.

Comment: Oh wait, that did it! I hadn't taken out the float on the middle column

Answer (score 1):

If you are, indeed, able to add a wrapper div element, then this works (insofar as your simple example) at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bFL8t/):

```
​#left {
    float: left;
}

​#wrap {
    width: 80%;
    float: right;
}

​#wrap #middle {
    float: left;
}

#wrap #right {
    float: right;
}​
```

Given the following HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="middle">middle</div>
    <div id="right">right</div>
</div>
<div id="left">left</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Bear in mind, though, that this is likely to be fairly fragile; and would be better achieved by re-ordering your mark-up, or, if that can't be changed server-side, or in the HTML, using JavaScript to move things around, for example:

```
var middle = document.getElementById('middle'),
    left = document.getElementById('left');

middle.parentNode.insertBefore(middle,left.nextSibling);​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bFL8t/1/).

Answer (score 0):

If widths and heights are set, use the css attribute:

```
position:absolute;
```

and play with:

```
left: 100px; /* width of the div on the left */
```

Answer (score 0):

Long after for the pleasure :
pout all 3 divs in side another than will have a text-align-center property (just for the middle div) and let the left and right divs float as answered.

```css
.group{
   text-align:center;
}

#left{
 display:inline-block;
   float:left;
}

#right{
   display:inline-block;
   float:right;
}

#middle{
 display:inline-block;

}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <div id="left">[left]</div>
  <div id="middle">[middle]</div>
  <div id="right">[right]</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Presuming it HAS to be in this order for some scraping tool grabbing the code relying on it being like this, why don't you just add some JavaScript to shuffle them about after the page has loaded.